# How to use result Objects in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, debugging

In the Android Studio debugger I have a WindowManager object which returns various members of that object in the Evaluation debugger. I want to use 'mGlobal' in the Activity,
[Debugging window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5VhI.png)
This is what I tried:

```
            Log.d("MainActivity",
                    "WinMAn : " + winMan.mGlobal);
```

This line returned an error :

> cannot resolve symbol mGlobal

but when I use this while debugging in Evaluation expression it works and returns the expected WindowManagerGlobal object

Comment: `WindowManager` is an interface and has no fields. `WindowManagerImpl` is not part of the Android SDK, as it is part of the internal implementation of the framework. And `mGlobal` is marked with `@UnsupportedAppUsage`, meaning you may run into problems on newer versions of Android if you try using reflection to access it.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for answering my question. I am pretty much convinced that this cannot be done but still ignoring your high reputation and all-time rank in StackOverflow I am still gonna ask, is there any way it can be done?

Comment: I do not know if that particular field is on the graylist or blacklist and so what the short-term ramifications are of trying to access it through reflection. And, bear in mind that device manufacturers can modify `WindowManagerImpl` as they see fit. If your objective is to use this for one app just on some personal device, feel free to try reflection and see how well it works. But, I would not distribute an app that relies upon this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment and I am not distributing this app this is just a small gig.